# Set position fixed to divs with jQuery or CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been trying to create an effect so that when you scroll in the browser, the **Div1** section doesn't move only the next section **Div2** will move up and cover the **Div1** section. Then when the **Div2** section hits the top on the edge of the browser, the **Div2** will stop moving and then the next section will move up and cover it and so on...

```css
body {
  padding-top: 180px;
}
div {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10;
}
div:first-child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
div:nth-child(even) {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <h1>Div1</h1>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <h1>Div2</h1>
</div>
<div id="div3">
  <h1>Div3</h1>
</div>
<div id="div4">
  <h1>Div4</h1>
</div>
<div id="div5">
  <h1>Div5</h1>
</div>
```

I have manage to achieve that effect for the first section with CSS but it doesn't seem to be a right solution. So I was hoping anyone could help me creating this affect with jQuery on scroll event?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Its in the question...

Comment: I don't see any jQuery code in the question. You can find lots of scroll event control by a simple search in google

Comment: I didn't said that I have tried with jQuery... I tried with CSS only... Because I don't know about jQuery that much...

Comment: I didn't find anything.. Thats why I posted this question... If I found anything why would I come here to ask?

Comment: Check out sticky.js ( http://stickyjs.com/ ) using this script will help you.

Comment: @Rob that stickjs seems what I'm looking for... But can this be applied on multiple elements?

Comment: Yes it can - Ive done it. You would use different "sticky" containers with different ID's and trigger them in the script.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this plugin @Rob ... :)

Answer (score 0):

So something like this will work but you do lose your background colors.

The main issue was that everytime you set a div to position fixed, it's no longer part of the scrolling area.

There should be a way to do this with just the window scrolling, I'll let that be a part 2 for you.

```js
$(".scroll").scroll(function() {
  $('.fixed').empty();
  $('.scroll').children().each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).offset().top < 0) {
      $('.fixed').empty();
      $('.fixed').append(
        $(element).clone()
      );
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.scroll {
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
}
.scroll > div {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10;
  color: black;
  width 100%;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  color #000;
}
.scroll > div:nth-child(even) {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">
  <div id="div1">
    <h1>Div1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <h1>Div2</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <h1>Div3</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="div4">
    <h1>Div4</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="div5">
    <h1>Div5</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fixed"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `z-index: 1` on your first child. This code should work to achieve what you wanted:

```
body {
  padding-top: 180px;
}
div {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10;
}
#div1{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#div2, #div4 {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: But how will the other divs will stop on top when scroll?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I'll have to look.

Comment: Sorry Omer, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Its ok... Rob gave me a superb solution... See the comments in my question. Thanks for your time @Ian